# Is there a way to use square brackets "[]" in JavaScript object arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, key

Is there a way to use square brackets "[]" in JavaScript object arrays? There is a square bracket in the key I am  trying to make and it is causing an error to fire.

For instance, I have an array of objects like this

```js
    var objectArray ={
        address[address_number] = "text"
    }
```

There is an error over the square bracket and when I try to run this code it fails.

Is there a way to use a bracket in the name of the key?

Comment: what is address ? and what final result you are looking for ?

Comment: Unclear what the expected result is. seems weird to have square brackets in a key, but quotes is all you may need.

Comment: Syntax error. If I got you right you need to split into `var objectArray = { address: []}` and `objectArray.address[address_number] = "text"`

Comment: Hello  Nishant! The reason there is square brackets in the key is due to an element on the page whos name attribute is name=address[address_number] and I am trying to use this as the key so I can write code to reference this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the data structure you want to achieve. This is an object with just one key:

```
var objectArray = { 
    'address[address_number]': 'text'
};
```

Then access the data like this:

```
console.log(objectArray['address[address_number]']); // Outputs 'text'
```

And this is more multi-dimensional:

```
var objectArray = { 
    address : {
        address_number : 'text'
    }
};
```

Then access the data like this:

```
console.log(objectArray.address.address_number); // Outputs 'text'
```

Comment: Thank you Luciano! Using quotes for the key worked and I am now able to run the code.

Answer (score 3):

It won't work the way you are trying to do it, but you can do accomplish what you want with an extra line of code

```
var objectArray ={
    address: []
};

objectArray.address[address_number] = 'text';
```

Comment: Hello BShaps, thank you for the reply! It seems that Nina's response was perfect for this without needing a second line of code. Just add quotes who knew!

Comment: @ErikBoud I'm confused why you would ever want the result created by Nina's solution, but if that is what you were looking for then great!

Answer (score 0):

You could use quotes for the key of the object.

```js
var object = { 'address[address_number]': "text" };

console.log(object);
```

Comment: That doesn't create an array

Comment: @BShaps, i don't think, that op wants to get an array. maybe the wrong term is just missing for an object.

Comment: I figured it was meant to be an array because the variable name is objectArray.

Comment: I am trying to get an array of objects with this. And this solution worked perfectly for me. When I return my array after adding in the quotes it now fires correctly.

Comment: @ErikBoud This doesn't give you an array of anything, it gives you an object with an attribute with the name "address[address_number]" that holds the value "text"

Comment: @BShaps I am trying to create an array of Objects, as there are many elements I want to grab but I am just using this one as an example.

I am trying to get about 10 objects in this array like so

var object = { 
      'address[address_number]': "text", 
       'address[address_zip]': "text", 
       'address[address_state]': "text", 
      'address[address_city]': "text"
};

Comment: @ErikBoud, and where is actually the problem with it?

Comment: Hello @nina, there was no issue with this one, it worked perfectly!

Comment: @ErikBoud `object` is an object, not an array.  `'address[address_number]'` is an attribute/key/property in the object.  `"text"` is a value for an attribute.